# After deleting node in linked list, printing the node list is showing deleted node

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In the code below, even after deleting a node (20) if I try to print all the nodes by passing deleted node as head in disguise, it is printing all the nodes along with the deleted node. Can someone please explain this behavior along with Garbage Collection in Java? How was it able to iterate all the nodes even though there is no next element for the deleted node (20)?

Node:

```
class Node{

    int nodeint;
    Node next;

    public Node(int nodeint){
        this.nodeint = nodeint;

    }

}
```

LinkedList:

```
public class linkedlist{

    Node head;
    //Node next;
    public linkedlist(Node obj){

        this.head = obj;
    }

    public Node addnodes(int news){
        Node newlink = new Node(news);
        newlink.next = head;
        head = newlink;
        return head;
    }

    public void printAllNodes(Node obj){
        Node current  = obj;
        while(current!=null){
            System.out.println(current.nodeint);
            current = current.next;

        }

    }

    public Node remove(){

        Node temp = head;
        head = head.next;
        return temp;
    }

    public void printHead(){

        System.out.println("This is the present head node"+head.nodeint);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){    

        Node obj1 = new Node(2);
        Node obj2 = new Node(3);
        Node obj3 = new Node(4);
        obj1.next  = obj2;
        obj2.next = obj3;
        obj3.next = null;
        linkedlist newobj = new linkedlist(obj1);
        Node obj = null;
        obj = newobj.addnodes(5);
        obj =newobj.addnodes(20);
        //System.out.println(obj.nodeint);
        newobj.printAllNodes(obj);
        obj = newobj.remove();
        System.out.println("A node is deleted");
        newobj.printAllNodes(obj);
        newobj.printHead();

    }
}
```

Output of this code:

> 20
>
> 5
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> A node is deleted
>
> 20
>
> 5
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> This is the present head node: 5

Comment: Thank you everyone, all the answers helped me in understanding the concept. I was just trying out Linked List by tweaking it in several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node 20 has still reference to the next node i.e node 5 in this case. It is not related to garbage collection. If you want that behavior **set temp.next == null** in your **remove method.**

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. Look:

```
This is the present head node: 5
```

The list still prints 20, because `linkedlist.printAllNodes` prints the list starting with a parameter, not with it's head. Change your method:

```
public void printAllNodes() {
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.println(current.nodeint);
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

and change the invocations:

```
newobj.printAllNodes(); // invoke without parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

First you store dependency inside the head node, then you assign new head in you list, but assigned dependency in old head stays as it was. Also remove() method return the old head. And then you print all nodes statring from old head.
Also i would like to admit, that you class looks very stange. I don't understand why internal dependencies shown in outer world. You difenitely need to discover sourcecode of LinkedList from Java libruary

Answer (score 1):

In `printAllNodes()`, instead of passing the node, do this

```
public void printAllNodes() {
    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.println(current.nodeint);
        current = current.next;
    }
}
```

And on `remove()`, return new head node instead of deleted node,

```
public Node remove(){
    Node temp = head;
    head = head.next;
    temp.next = null;  //removing link to next node
    return head;  //returning head. Not deleted node
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: Your `remove()` function removes head from the linked list you invoke it on, but also returns the deleted head and this former head still has its `next` property pointing to the next node (which is the current head).

When you called  `newobj.printAllNodes(obj);` you passed the returned former head as the parameter.

Solution 1: You could have called this as `newobj.printAllNodes(newobj.head);`

Solution 2: Do what @hege_hegedus suggested